# creating pipes in java swt with many sources

Tags: java, swt, gstreamer

I'm new in gstreamer-java,
I'm doing a java swt project using gstreamer, and I read tutorials and
other things to do it.
I've decided to write pipes first, that I tested with command line,
and all pipes works fine.
But now I would like to use it in my java code.
I tried "pipeline.launch", for example for this pipe:
" v4l2src ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,height=240 ! xvimagesink
autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! alsasink "
(to get webcam output and audio output simultaneaously)

But the result is not what was expected, that is, I got two windows,
instead of one. One for the webcam output, and another which contains
nothing. I understand that it's because there is a window that is
generated with the pipe.

I learn now that I should use videocomponent to include the webcam
stream into my particular frame.
I tried this:

```
                   Display display = new Display();
                   Shell shell = new Shell(display);  // my frame
                   Pipeline pipe = new Pipeline("Webcam");
                   Element src = ElementFactory.make("v4l2src", "sourcevideo"); // the
```

first source
                       Element src2 = ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosrc", "sourceaudio") //
the second source

```
                   VideoComponent videocomponent = new VideoComponent(shell, SWT.NONE,
```

true); //including into my frame

```
                   videocomponent.getElement().setName("webcam");
                   videocomponent.setKeepAspect(true);
                   videocomponent.setLayoutData(new GridData());

                   Element videosink = videocomponent.getElement();
                   Element audiosink = ElementFactory.make("alsasink",
```

"sortieaudio"); //for the audio output
                       videocomponent.setBounds(25, 65, 420, 320);

```
                   pipe.addMany(src, videosink,src2, audiosink);
                   Element.linkMany(src, videosink, src2, audiosink);
                   pipe.play();
                   shell.open();
```

but there is a bug with the webcam.The video stream stopped, and there
is no audio output.
Can someone help me? I'm really confused!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solution elsewhere.
For this pipe,

> gst-launch -ev v4l2src ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,height=240 ! xvimagesink autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! alsasink

This is the solution in gstreamer-java, without using "Pipeline.launch":

- First of all, I created the component video of my custom shell:

> VideoComponent videocomponent = new VideoComponent(shell, SWT.NONE, true);
>   videocomponent.getElement().setName("webcam");
>   videocomponent.setKeepAspect(true);
>   videocomponent.setLayoutData(new GridData());

- then, I created elements of the pipe:

> Element videosource, videosink, audiosource, audioconv, audiosink;
>   videosource = ElementFactory.make("v4l2src", "sourcevid");
>   audiosource = ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosrc", "sourceaud");
>   audioconv = ElementFactory.make("audiconvert", "conv");
>   audiosink = ElementFactory.make("alsasink", "DestAud");
>   videosink = videocomponent.getElement();

- Now, I added this elements in the pipe:

> pipe.addMany(videosrc, videosink, audiosrc, audioconv, audiosrc, videosink);

- Then, I linked elements

> Element.linkMany(videosrc,videosink);
>   Element.linkMany(audiosrc, audioconv, audiosink);

- Finally, play the pipe:

> pipe.play();

- And open the window:

> shell.open();

If this can help someone, it would be good!
Bye